# How do templates differentiate types?

Tags: c++, templates

EDIT to clarify the question, even if I already got the answer:
On 2 different machines (a 32 bit microcontroller and a 32 bit desktop PC) with GCC (around same version) 2 templates, one with parameter **int** and the other with parameter **int32_t** sees these types, both 32 bit in size, as different in one machine and identical types in the other.
The question was "why it does so". I got a good answer (the **int32_t** type is a typedef on **int** type on one machine and on **long** type on the other).

I have this template (placeholder)

```
template<typename T> void PushValue(HSQUIRRELVM vm, T val) {
    DEBUG_ERROR("Dummy PushValue called, type is %s\n", typeid(T).name());
}
```

And these specializations which should cover all integer types.

```
template<> void PushValue<int8_t  >(HSQUIRRELVM vm, int8_t val  );
template<> void PushValue<int16_t >(HSQUIRRELVM vm, int16_t val );
template<> void PushValue<int32_t >(HSQUIRRELVM vm, int32_t val );
template<> void PushValue<int64_t >(HSQUIRRELVM vm, int64_t val );
template<> void PushValue<uint8_t >(HSQUIRRELVM vm, uint8_t val );
template<> void PushValue<uint16_t>(HSQUIRRELVM vm, uint16_t val);
template<> void PushValue<uint32_t>(HSQUIRRELVM vm, uint32_t val);
template<> void PushValue<uint64_t>(HSQUIRRELVM vm, uint64_t val);
```

I said "should" because they don't catch '**int**' and '**unsigned int**'; i had to add both of them. But, when I added also the '**long**' versions, so '**long int**' and so on, the compiler complained about duplicates, telling that '**long int**' is identical to '**int32_t**', for example.
So... if it's able to know that **long int** is identical to **int32_t**, why it takes **int** and **int32_t** which on my compiler (32 bit MIPS processor, GCC) should be identical, as different types ?
Second question : is it possible to make a 'catch all' template that is applied to a group of types ?

EDIT: I tested same code on a desktop (32 and 64 bit versions) and there the compiler (also GCC) takes **int** and **int32_t** as **IDENTICAL** types, giving an error of duplicated functions for the 2 added template variants. So on the desktop I have to remove the 2 additional specializations, and on the embedded code I have to add them.

EDIT:
On a 32 bit microcontroller, GCC:

```
Sizeof(int)    :4
typeid(int)    :i
Sizeof(int32_t):4
typeid(int32_t):l
Sizeof(long)   :4
typeid(long)   :l
```

On a 64 bit PC, GCC

```
sizeof(int)     : 4
typeid(int)     : i
sizeof(int32_t) : 4
typeid(int32_t) : i
sizeof(long)    : 8
typeid(long)    : l
```

On a 32 bit PC, GCC

```
sizeof(int)     : 4
typeid(int)     : i
sizeof(int32_t) : 4
typeid(int32_t) : i
sizeof(long)    : 4
typeid(long)    : l
```

As can be seen here, GCC takes as different types integers with same size and, on 2 differents platforms, it gives 2 different meanings for int32_t (long on MIPS, int on i386)

Comment: For example, a template that can catch all signed integer types.
In my cases they must convert anyways the value in int32_t type, the inner code is identical on all of them.

Comment: And then why long int is taken as int32_t ? also long int shouldn't be a fixed type.

Comment: Please consult the [function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) and the [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) reference.

Comment: "int and int32_t which on my compiler (32 bit MIPS processor, GCC) should be identical" ...pardon, but how exactly does having a 32-bit MIPS processor and GCC imply that int and int32_t either _are_, or _should be_, the same type?

Comment: I should have explained myself better... in my setup int IS an int32_t, or, better, is a 32 bit signed integer. So, their implementation is identical, but GCC takes them as different, which I can understand. But what I don't understand is why it takes long int and int32_t identical, for example. AFAIK long int could be easily an int64_t in some situations.

Comment: @Ron I looked at your links, but still no hints. If you look at my original (edited) question, 2 versions of GCC behaves differently on this. On the embedded controller int and int32_t are taken as different types (but they're both 32 bit signed!) and on a desktop PC they're taken as the same type.

Comment: @Max You're making a bad assumption... that being, that if `int` is a 32 bit int type, and `int32_t` is a 32 bit int type, then `int` must be `int32_t`.  But you just demonstrated that wrong before posting the question; `long` is an `int32_t` in your setup.

Comment: @H Walters, no, if you look at my edited post, that's wrong. GCC takes 2 integer types with 32 bit width as DIFFERENT types, and it also makes different choices on 2 different 32 bit platforms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, `short` and `int` are both 16 bits wide, `int16_t` will be a synonym for one of them but not for the other. If you want to cover all the integral types, use the signed/unsigned variants of `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long`. Don’t use the fixed-size typedefs. As you’ve seen, they don’t cover all of the integer types.

Comment: I guess that's the right answer to my question, at least from what I've seen in my latest tests. Normally on microcontrollers I use always fixed-size types, but I see that on templates I shall replace them with normal types. Thank you!

Comment: @Max — note that that’s what you need if you want to **define** all the specializations. Having done that, you can **call** them with fixed-size types; they are all typedefs for builtin types.